# Matching query doesn't exist?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-rest-auth

I am making a retweet function and it works quite smooth but I am not able to retweet my own tweets , I am able to retweet other users tweets but not mine
. It shows that matching query doesn't exist.

Here is the tweets models

```
class TweetManager(models.Manager):
   def retweet(self,user,parent_obj):
    if parent_obj.parent:
        obj_parent = parent_obj.parent
    else:
        obj_parent = parent_obj

    qs = self.get_queryset().filter(user = user, parent = obj_parent)
    if qs.exists():
        return None

    obj = self.model(
        user = user,
        parent = obj_parent,
        content = parent_obj.content

        )

    obj.save()

    return obj      



class Tweet(models.Model):
   parent = models.ForeignKey("self",blank = True,null = True)
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
   content = models.CharField(max_length = 130)
   time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
   objects = TweetManager()

   def __str__(self):
       return self.content

   class Meta:
       ordering = ['content']
```

Here's the views.py

```
 class Retweet(View):
    def get(self, request, pk, *args, **kwargs):
      tweet = get_object_or_404(Tweet, pk=pk)
      if request.user.is_authenticated:
        new_tweet = Tweet.objects.retweet(request.user, tweet)
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
    return HttpResponseRedirect(tweet.get_absolute_url())
```

Comment: `self.get_queryset().filter(user = user, parent = obj_parent)` this line returns the tweet you did, and if exists it returns none. so its the correct behavior.

Comment: No it still doesn't work.

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: Tweet matching query does not exist.

Comment: i dont think that is coming from the manager, i think its coming from the get_object_or_404, check the database if you have a tweet with that id

Comment: Yeah i have a tweet with that id basically it just retweets the tweets of other users but when it comes to retweet my own tweets , It throws  this error.